# what is the quivalent of 'cvs update' in tfs

Tags: tfs

I am new to tfs, and i'm using the command line version (linux) of it.

In porting some scripts, I would like to confirm the tfs equivalent for the following cvs command:

`cvs update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to a CVS update in TFS is to do a recursive get latest:

```
tf get /recursive
```